# Gson serializer for ZonedDateTime from java.time

Tags: android, gson, retrofit, retrofit2, java-time

I use `Retrofit2` with `Gson`. I wrote a custom serializer for `ZonedDateTime` but it's not working. When I try to debug sending requests to the server, I see that the bugger does not enter the `serialize` method at all.
Here is my `ZonedDateTimeSerializer`:

```
class ZonedDateTimeSerializer : JsonSerializer<ZonedDateTime?> {

    override fun serialize(localDate: ZonedDateTime?, srcType: Type?, context: JsonSerializationContext?): JsonElement {
        val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT
        return JsonPrimitive(formatter.format(localDate))
    }

}
```

I also add this line to `GsonBuilder`:

```
.registerTypeAdapter(ZonedDateTime::class.java, ZonedDateTimeSerializer())
```

In the retrofit request, I have a query parameter with `ZonedDateTime` type:

```
@Query("since") since: ZonedDateTime
```

I don't completely understand why this doesn't work because I have a very similar serializer for LocalDate, and is everything okay with it:

```
class LocalDateSerializer : JsonSerializer<LocalDate?> {

    override fun serialize(localDate: LocalDate?, srcType: Type?, context: JsonSerializationContext?): JsonElement {
        val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
        return JsonPrimitive(formatter.format(localDate))
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide a small complete Retrofit example which shows that your `LocalDateSerializer` is working but your `ZonedDateTimeSerializer` is not. Just to rule out any other errors, can you please verify that you imported `java.time.ZonedDateTime` and not `ZonedDateTime` from the ThreeTen backport project (in case you have that on your classpath).

Comment: @Marcono1234So, I created a gist in github and while I was doing it, I found the main difference. `LocalDate` is used only in the DTO object that is passed as the `@Body` of the request. But I'm trying to use the `ZonedDateTimeSerializer` as a `@Query` parameter. Perhaps I need to act differently for this situation? I understand that it would be easier to just convert the date to a string and pass it as such, but I would like to know if there is a difference between an adapter for a parameter query and a field in a dto object. By the way, I don't use `ThreeTen`

Answer (score -1):

```
class ZonedDateTimeSerializer : JsonSerializer<ZonedDateTime?> {

    override fun serialize(localDate: ZonedDateTime?, srcType: Type?, context: JsonSerializationContext?): JsonElement {
        val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(ISO_INSTANT)
        return JsonPrimitive(formatter.format(localDate))
    }
}
```

I think you just missed ofPattern

Comment: But what's the difference? Both use `DateTimeFormatter`. But in the ZonedDateTimeSerializer I use constant from class `DateTimeFormatter` . Here is it: ```public static final DateTimeFormatter ISO_INSTANT;```
Also, as I indicated in the question, the debugger does not enter the `serialize` method at all. Also method `ofPattern` can only take a `string` as a parameter